# Como setar o scroll pro topo da pagina usando utilizando rotas?

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso setar pro topo da pagina toda vez que navegar entre as páginas no sidenavbar.

```js
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public user: User | undefined;
  public menuItems: Array<ISideMenuItem> = [
    // Esses item irao voltar a medida que forem adicionado
    { id: 1, name: 'home', icon: '/assets/icons/home.svg', link: '/home' },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'chargers',
      icon: '/assets/icons/charger.svg',
      link: '/chargers',
    },
    // {id: 3, name: 'operations', icon: 'file-earmark-text', link: '/extracts'},
    // {id: 4, name: 'transactions', icon: 'currency-dollar', link: '/receivements'},
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'indicators',
      icon: '/assets/icons/indicator-menu.svg',
      link: '/indicators',
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'settings',
      icon: '/assets/icons/settings.svg',
      link: '/settings',
    },
    //{id: 7, name: 'support', icon: '/assets/icons/message.svg', link: '/support'},
  ];

  constructor(
    private translateConfigService: TranslateConfigService,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

  public loggOut(): void {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu-container" id="side-menu-container">
<ul class="list-group menu"  >
    <div class="ml-2" ><hr class="line"/></div>
    <li
        *ngFor="let item of menuItems"
        routerLinkActive="active-link-menu"
        [routerLink]="item.link" routerLinkActive="active-link-menu"

        >
        <div class="d-flex flex-column ">
            <div *ngIf="item.name === 'settings'" class="ml-2" ><hr class="line"/></div>
            <div class="d-flex list-group-item list-group-item-action menu-item">
                <div class="icon-content">
                    <div class="menu-item-icon"
                    [style]="'-webkit-mask: url('+item.icon+') no-repeat center / contain; mask: url('+item.icon+') no-repeat center / contain;'"
                    width="1rem"   height="1.5rem"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="text-content" translate>
                    sideMenu.{{item.name}}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>

        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action menu-item"  (click)="loggOut()"   >
            <div class="icon-content">
                <div class="menu-item-icon"
                [style]="'-webkit-mask: url(/assets/icons/exit.svg) no-repeat center / contain; mask: url(/assets/icons/exit.svg) no-repeat center / contain;'"
                    width="1rem"   height="1.5rem"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-content" translate>
                sideMenu.exit
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="profile-container">
        <div class="picture-container">
            <div  class="profile-icon" [style]="'-webkit-mask: url(/assets/icons/profile.svg) no-repeat center / contain; mask: url(/assets/icons/profile.svg) no-repeat center / contain;'"   >   </div>
        </div>
            {{ user?.email }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Voce pode importar o Router e chamar uma função que vai fazer o scroll sempre que a rota for alterada.

constructor(private router: Router) {
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
// see also
console.log(val instanceof NavigationEnd)
});
}